# How to print out the index of an odd number in python

Tags: python

My goal is to print out a new list of the index of any odd numbers that a user enter into a list. For example, if the list is [1,2,5,15,4,7] I would like the output to be a list that contains the indexes of the odd numbers like so: [0,2,3,5]

```
length=int(input('Please enter how long you want your list: '))
list1=[ ]
for i in range(length):
    list1.append(int(input('Please enter an integer: ')))
print(list1)

odd_i = [] 
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
if i % 2:
    pass
else:
    odd_i.append(list1[i])
print(odd_i)
```

That is the code I have written, the current output for the example given above is [1,5,15,7] but I would like the index of the odd numbers to be printed [0,2,3,5], not the odd number itself.

Comment: `odd_i.append(i)`

Comment: And use `continue` instead of `pass` in this case

Comment: he actually do not need ```pass```. you can just use ```if i%2==1``` and no ```else```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing whether the index is odd or even, not the value.

Use `enumerate()` to iterate over the indexes and values.

```
for index, value in enumerate(list1):
    if value % 2 == 1:
        odd_i.append(index)
```

Also, your test is backwards, you're appending the even elements, not the odd ones.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Your issue is that you're performing the modulus operator on the indexes themselves rather than the values of the array. Also you're appending the values at the indexes into the array rather than the indexes.

**So the quick fix:**

```py
odd_i = [] 
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    if list1[i] % 2:
        continue
    else:
        odd_i.append(i)
print(odd_i)
```

If any value of the array is **not** evenly divisible, then **append that index**, otherwise **continue**.